# How to add an existing node to the start of my linked list?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, addition

This is for a school assignment could someone point me in the right direction. I am trying to split a linked list between odds and evens using recursion, but something seems to be wrong with the .add(IntNode), it keeps alternating between the first 2 nodes like it is overwriting it. I have troubleshoot everything i can think of, it seem i using the add incorrectly. I have to edit the odds and evens methods and leave the original linked list empty.

here is my code, any help would be appreciated.

Test Code:

```
public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        IntLinkedList test = new IntLinkedList(new int[]{3,5,4,6,8,2,1,4,3,2,5,3,6,3});
        System.out.println("Test list: "+test);

        IntLinkedList oddOnes = new IntLinkedList(), evenOnes = new IntLinkedList();
        test.split(oddOnes,evenOnes);
        System.out.println("Test list should be empty: "+test);
        System.out.println("Odds: "+oddOnes);
        System.out.println("Evens: "+evenOnes);
    }

}
```

IntLinkedList relevant methods:

```
public void add(IntNode node) { 
    if (first != null) {
        node.setNext(first);
        first = node;
    } else {
        first = node;
    }
}

public void split(IntLinkedList odds, IntLinkedList evens) {
    IntNode curr = first;

     if (curr != null) {
        if (curr.getData() % 2 == 0) {
            evens.add(curr);
        } else {
            odds.add(curr);
        }
        System.out.println(curr.getData());
        remove(0);
        split(odds, evens);
    }
}

public void remove(int index) {
    IntNode curr = first;
    IntNode past = null;
    int currIndex = 0;

    while (curr != null && currIndex < index) {
        past = curr;
        curr = curr.getNext();
        currIndex++;
    }

    if (past == null && curr != null && index > -1) {
        first = first.getNext();
        curr.setNext(null);
    } else if (curr != null && index > -1) {
        past.setNext(curr.getNext());
    }
}
```

IntNode:

```
public class IntNode {

    private int number;
    private IntNode nextInt;

    public IntNode(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public IntNode(int number, IntNode next) {
        this.number = number;
        this.nextInt = next;
    }

    public IntNode getNext() {
        return nextInt;
    }

    public void setNext(IntNode nextInt) {
        this.nextInt = nextInt;
    }

    public int getData() {
        return number;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include your `remove()` method as well

Comment: i updated my post to include it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to remove the current node before you add it into the odd or even list. Otherwise you will modify the source list at the "add" method call.

```
System.out.println(curr.getData());
remove(0);
if (curr.getData() % 2 == 0) {
    evens.add(curr);
} else {
    odds.add(curr);
}
split(odds, evens);
```